# On hardness of finding total dominating sets in triangle-free graphs

Tags: graphs, reference-request, np-hard, combinatorics

A *total dominating set* $S\subset V(G)$ is a set of vertices such that $\forall v\in V(G)$, $v$ has a neighbour in $S$. The *minimum total dominating set* of $G$ is a total dominating set of $G$ of minimum possible size. The *minimum total domination number* of $G$ is represented by $\gamma_t(G)$.It is known that MTDS is $NP-complete$ for general graphs, bipartite graphs, chordal graphs, etc. [**REFERENCE**: Henning, Michael A.. “A survey of selected recent results on total domination in graphs.” Discret. Math. 309 (2009): 32-63.]

**Do we know anything about hardness of MTDS on *triangle-free* graphs of bounded degree?Or *triangle-free* graphs in general?** ( A graph is *triangle-free* if any three vertices does not form a triangle).

Comment: All bipartites are triangle free. That answers your second question.

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: It would be good if you could tell the motivation for studying this version since there could be many such variants.

Comment: So I am studying this specific kind of proper coloring of graphs called "*cd-coloring*" in which every color class is dominated by atleast one vertex. The *cd-chromatic number* is denoted by $\chi_{cd}$. So it is proven that for triangle -free graphs $G$ ,$\chi_{cd}(G)=\gamma_t(G)$. Right now my motive is to study cd-colorability in regular graphs(in particular *cubic* graphs). I want to prove this is $NP-hard$ for triangle-free cubic graphs. So I tried to reduce  *total domination in cubic graphs*(which is $NP-complete$) to cd -colorability in cubic graphs, but till now am not successful.

Comment: (*Continuing*) So I am searching for total-domination $NP-completeness$ results for *triangle-free* graphs of bounded degree, So that I can reduce it to *cd-colorability* of some triangle-free $k$-regular graphs, thereby proving it $NP-complete$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is indeed $\mathsf{NP}$-hard on bipartite graphs (which are triangle-tree) of degree at most $3$. See Theorem 6 of [this paper](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1655925.1655948).